# Web Crawler not printing pages correctly

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

Good morning !

I've developed a very simple spider with Scrapy just to get used with FormRequest. I'm trying to send a request to this page: https://www.caramigo.eu/ which should lead me to a page like this one: https://www.caramigo.eu/be/fr/recherche?address=Belgique%2C+Li%C3%A8ge&date_debut=16-03-2019&date_fin=17-03-2019. The issue is that my spider does not prompt the page correctly (the cars images and info do not appear at all) and therefore I can't collect any data from it. Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy


class CarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "caramigo"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.caramigo.eu/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.search_line)

    def search_line(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'address': 'Belgique, Liège', 'date_debut': '16-03-2019', 'date_fin': '17-03-2019'},
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'caramigo.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Sorry if the syntax is not correct, I'm pretty new to coding.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: This website uses Javascript to render the frontend. Scrapy cannot render any Javascript by itself. You need to either use [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/) to render Javascript, or alternatively scrape their API (e.g. https://www.caramigo.eu/services/car).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Now I'm wondering how do I get the API for each request I'll make ? I mean, on the homepage I have to launch a request for the location and date. After that I need the API. Have you some hint on how I can implement this ?

Comment: You need to use your browser's developer tools to inspect those API calls as you make them. For example, submit the form and then look at what values are sent. Here is a quick guide from Scrapy's documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#the-network-tool

Comment: Thanks a lot again !